# Facebook SDK error in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using fb sdk in my project where from app user can share on his fb wall. The app works well with 2.3.6 but fails for 4.0 or higher version. This is the error which I get [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android apps using the Facebook SDK need to register a key hash with their [developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/) which will be used for verifying your app. You can get detailed instructions on how to generate and register a key hash on their g[etting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).